# Product Reviews

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for free datasets of product reviews. At minimum I need the following values for each record:

- Rating (e.g. 2/5 stars, or 40%)
- Product Name / Description (e.g. iPhone 5s)
- Reviewer (e.g. Wired magazine)

Any additional values would be a bonus, such as:

- Category (e.g. Smartphone)
- Price
- Date

I particularly want products reviewed by magazines/websites (i.e. journalists rather than the public) as I am investigating the skew of product reviews from a neutral source (e.g.is it more likely that a magazine will rate a product higher because it has to consider its income stream from advertising?). I am interested in reviews of ANYTHING, and would love to build a dataset from a diverse range of reviewers.

*So far I have managed to scrape some reviews from websites and have datasets of album reviews, bike reviews and a small dataset of consumer tech reviews. This is quite a time-consuming process so it would be great if there was pre-existing datasets of this ilk.*

Comment: Not to be *too* discouraging but I think the only place you'll find something like this is as part of a curated data set that was created for similar research purposes as yours. Assuming you looked into if a similar project had been executed before, I dont think you'll find anything else except for: a) data sets from a single site such as Amazon/Google which will all be UGC (user generated content), b) have to screen scrape from either the product site (will be clearly biased) and/or from across the internet which may bring up copyright concerns. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

amazon:
This dataset consists of reviews from amazon. The data span a period of 18 years, including ~35 million reviews up to March 2013. Reviews include product and user information, ratings, and a plaintext review.
http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Amazon.html
beer advocate reviews:
http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-BeerAdvocate.html
rate beer reviews:
http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-RateBeer.html
movie reviews via rotten tomatoes:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/sentiment-analysis-on-movie-reviews